# jqGrid treegrid column data binding

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

Following is the colmodel of my jqgrid(treegrid).
I am binding the data to this grid using with database query result. Here column names I am getting from the database is same as name attributes in the colmodel. But the problem is the data of **"isCategory"** is binding to the **"condition"** column.

```
colNames: ['id', 'Name', 'isCategory','Condition'],

colModel: [
{ name: 'schoolid', width: 0, sortable: false, hidden: true, key: true },

{ name: 'Name', index: 'name', width: 500, sortable: false },

{ name: 'isCategory', index: 'isCategory', width: 0, sortable: false},

{ name: 'Condition',index: 'Condition', width: 0, sortable: false},

]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean under "binding the data to this grid" because jqGrid is pure JavaScript plugin. The statement 'the data of "isCategory" is binding to the "condition" column' is also unclear. Which `datatype` you use (`"json"`, `"xml"`, `"local"` or other)? How JSON/XML data returned from the server looks like? An example of server response and more full JavaScript code could clear many opened questions.

Comment: The "treedatatype" is "xml" and it is "adjacency" .getSchoolData is a web method which will call sql procedure that returns a table with column names(Schoolid,Name,isCategory,Condition). Now the data of "isCategory" column of sql procedure result table is  coming in "Condition" column of jqgrid(treegrid(xml  datatype)). $("#SchoolAttatch").jqGrid({
                url: "SchoolAttatch.aspx?getSchoolData",
                 treedatatype: "xml", 
                 mtype: "GET", 
                treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                height: 'auto',colNames and colModel are as above

Comment: Could you click on "edit" link below your question and modify the text of your question? Could you insert an example of XML response from the server. If you use any `xmlReader` then you should include the value of the parameter too. Do you implemented server side paging in `getSchoolData`? Could you clear what problem you have currently and what you mean under "binding" the data of "isCategory" to the "condition" column? Do you want to have the same data in 'Condition' and 'isCategory' columns of the grid?